# Java - ObjectInputStream boolean assignment within while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, null, boolean, objectinputstream

Pretty simple question but say I want to use a while loop to wait for input to my ObjectInputStream as below:

```
while ((messageObject = objectInputStream.readObject()) != null) {
    // Do something once object is passed through inputstream
}
```

How could I implement this using ObjectInputStream's readBoolean method without casting the boolean as something else?

e.g:

```
while ((messageBoolean = objectInputStream.readBoolean()) != null) {
    // Do something once boolean is passed through inputstream
}
```

The code above simply gives a compile time error: incomparable types: boolean and <'null>

EDIT: I should clarify:

```
objectInputStream = ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
```

Comment: Your null comparison doesn't actually do the correct thing. It's possible to have a `null` in the `ObjectInputStream` and it doesn't indicate the end of the file. You should catch an `EOFException`, not look for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
boolean valueRead=false;
boolean endOfFile=false;
while(!endOfFile) {
    try { 
        valueRead = objectInputStream.readBoolean();
        //Do something with the boolean 
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        endOfFile = true;
    } 
}
```

Take a look at [readBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readBoolean--)

Comment: I'd remove the `catch (Exception e)` clause. It's really not recommended to have a catch-all. Other exceptions should be handled specifically, and not necessarily inside the `while`, and their handling is not really relevant for the answer anyway.

Comment: Yes, but you can't remove that catch or  the loop will be endless. To handle the exception in other place just throw it again

Comment: Why will the loop be endless? If an uncaught exception is thrown, it breaks the while, and everything else until it is caught.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You're right, I was thinking about another think while writing that comment